# React Jest Testing : How to test image is left aligned according to input parameter

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library, react-testing

I have to create react component having image and text box, so My task is to test

1. Image or Text box is Left or right aligned , as needed
2. Image or Text box is Top or bottom aligned, as needed

By passing input variant as **textLeft** or **textRight**

**Example Component**

[image]

**Any Help?**

Comment: Are you using react-testing-library or something else?

Comment: @RichardHpa react-testing-libray,

Answer (score 1):

If they both had the same `aria-label` or another selector you could use the `getAllBy` query which would give you an array of items in order they find them so then you could check the children by using `within` to query inside those.

Something like this would work.

```js
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div aria-label="card">
        <img alt="image example" />
      </div>
      <div aria-label="card">
        <h1>This is heading</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

import { render, screen, within } from '@testing-library/react'

test('React Testing Library works!', () => {
  render(<Component />)
  const cards = screen.getAllByLabelText('card')
  expect(cards).toHaveLength(2)
  expect(within(cards[0]).getByAltText('image example'))
  expect(within(cards[1]).queryByAltText('image example')).not.toBeInTheDocument()

  expect(within(cards[1]).getByText('This is heading'))
  expect(within(cards[0]).queryByText('This is heading')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
})
```